# In Github, are PR reviewers notified when a new commit has been made after they request changes?

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for SO but say I make a PR in Github and the reviewers of the PR request changes before it is merged.  When I subsequently commit the requested changes on my branch that I am trying to merge are the reviewers notified that I have made the change? Or do I need to explicitly comment on the PR that I have made the change and tag the reviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I subsequently commit the requested changes on my branch that I am trying to merge are the reviewers notified that I have made the change?

They will be able to see/notified you made a new commit, but they won't know if it addresses the PR concerns (or if you're simply adding unrelated changes). Best practice is to comment on the PR and tell them you made changes - tagging the reviewer(s) definitely won't hurt!

Answer (score 1):

Since February 2019, no need to comment: you can [Re-request review on a pull request](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-re-request-review-on-a-pull-request/)

> If changes have been made to a pull request that has already been reviewed, you can now re-request a review with a single click in the pull request’s sidebar. This will notify the requested reviewers that changes have been made.

Comment: The repo I am working with must have this disabled because I don't see any "re-review" button

Comment: @user1893354 Do you mean that, as described in https://help.github.com/en/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review, you do not have a "Reviewers" section in the right sidebar, after selecting a Pull Request?

Comment: there is a "Reviewers" sections, however the button mentioned in step 7 (the double circular arrows) doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: @user1893354 step 7 is for requesting a re-review. If that person was *not* involved in a review, it would stand to reason a re-review would not be an available option. Would they be available in step 5?

Comment: In the "Reviewers" section it lists two reviewers who had made reviews and had requested changes.

Comment: @user1893354 Then it would be interesting to contact GitHub support (https://github.com/contact) and ask why that feature is not available.

Comment: I just did that.  Maybe there is an issue with my account

Comment: @user1893354 Great! Keep us posted.